# Django factory-boy custom provider

Tags: django, pytest, faker, factory-boy

I would like to create my own customer Faker provider.

I am using factory-boy which comes already with Faker included, so in my test factories I am using for a UserFactory

```py
name = factory.Faker('name')
```

My question is, can I somehow implement my own custom provider? So I could use `factory.Faker('my_provider')`? Or for that I would have to swap all factory.Faker() instances and just use Faker() instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the `BaseProvider` class and define your custom functions. Afterwards you can add it to a `Faker` object.

There are two possible options:

## 1. Retrieve factory Faker object from factory library and add custom provider.

In this scenario you retrieve the instantiated `Faker` object from the `factory` library using a private get method. Please note, it is bad practice to access private methods outside of a class.

```py
import factory
from faker import providers

class HelloWorldProvider(providers.BaseProvider):
    """Use provider to generate `hello world`.""" 
    def hello_world(self) -> str:
        """Say hello to the world"""
        return "hello world"
factory.Faker.add_provider(HelloWorldProvider)

fake = factory.Faker._get_faker()
print(fake.hello_world())
```

## 2. Instantiate new Faker object and add custom provider

With this option you achieve the same result without accessing any private methods outside of the class. I would advise on this course of action.

```py
import faker

fake = faker.Faker()


class HelloWorldProvider(faker.providers.BaseProvider):
    """Use provider to generate `hello world`.""" 

    def hello_world(self) -> str:
        """Say hello to the world"""
        return "hello world"

fake.add_provider(HelloWorldProvider)
print(fake.hello_world())
```

[Faker BaseProvider reference](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/baseprovider.html)